# Alternating sum of polygamma functions

Tags: sequences-and-series

I've come across the following sum while doing a problem:

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \psi^{(1)}(m+np)$$

Where $m \in (0,\infty)$ and $p \in \mathbb{N}$ and $\psi^{(1)}$ denotes the first derivative of the digamma function. It looks so clean that I feel there must be a closed form for this, but I am not super used to working with these types of functions.

Does anyone know if this is a well known sum, or have any idea of how to solve this?

I have though about writing it in the following way: 
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\int_0^\infty \frac{t e^{-(m+np)t}}{1-e^{-t}} dt$$

And then switching the order of integration but it doesn't seem to lead to anything obviously advantageous. Thanks.

Comment: $$\psi^{(1)}(x+1)=\frac{\pi^2}6-\sum_{n=1}^x\frac1{n^2}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac1{(x+1+n)^2}$$
See if that helps?

Comment: $$=\frac{\pi^2}6-\int_0^1\frac1a\int_0^a\frac{t^x-1}{t-1}dtda$$

Comment: Just by the alternating series test it does - $\psi^{(1)} (n) \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.